Run a VPN server alongside a website served by Docker
I have a server running this CMS as a website by running a Docker file like this by docker-compose which internally uses nginxproxy/nginx-proxy and nginxproxy/acme-companion Docker images.
Now, I intend to follow the instructions given here to set up a VPN on the same server which uses Let's Encrypt.
Question
Can I run the VPN alongside the previous CMS? Would I run into any trouble?

If I totally stop the currently running CMS by docker-compose and then set up and run the VPN, can I switch between CMS and VPN regularly by stopping one and starting the other? Or would the new VPN setup interfere with the CMS setup?
